# Why can't I display the details of my tree model

Tags: r

When I type down the name of my tree model, I keep getting this error and I have no idea about what it means.

Here is my code, OJ is a dataset contained in package "ISLR"

```
library(tree)
library(ISLR)
library(tidyverse)
library(caTools)
library(randomForest)
library(MASS)
library(rpart)
library(gbm)
library(glmnet)
# 8.4.9
## a. split the data into train and test
OJ <- OJ
set.seed(2)
train2 <- sample.split(OJ$Purchase, SplitRatio = 800/1070)
OJ_train <- subset(OJ, train2 == T)
OJ_test <- subset(OJ, train2 == F)

## b. fit a tree model
OJ_train_tree <- tree(Purchase ~ ., data = OJ_train)
summary(OJ_train_tree)

## c. a closer look at the model detail (here is the error)
OJ_train_tree
```

And the error I got is

> OJ_train_tree
> Error in cat(x, ..., sep = sep) :
> argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'

Comment: Without reproducible data, there is no way to answer this. I have used the example data `cpus` on the `tree` manual page (?tree) and your code and I get no error. The problem seems to be with your data or with code that you did not include in your post. Your formula, `Purchase~.` includes all of the variables in Oj so perhaps one of them is causing the problem.

Comment: Do you really need to add 9 packages for 8 lines of code? Please pare down your code to what is needed so that we don't have to work so hard to figure out what is going on.

Comment: This works fine for me without any error. Restart R and try it on fresh R session. Use `caTools::sample.split` and `tree::tree` to avoid naming conflict.